# ReactDOM doesn't render the app, even though application 'compiles sucessfully'

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, render, react-dom

I have encountered a problem with th fact that reactDOM.render doesnt render the app despite yarn run compiling sucessfully.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {PersistGate} from 'redux-persist/integration/react';
import {store ,persistor} from './redux/store.js'

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
              <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
                  <App />
              </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Redux configuration in store.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import logger from 'redux-logger';
import {persistStore} from 'redux-persist';

import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
import { fetchGalleryStart } from './gallery/gallery.saga';

import {rootReducer} from './root.reducer.js';
const sagaMiddleware= createSagaMiddleware();

const middlewares = [sagaMiddleware];
if (process.env.NODE_ENV==='development') {
    middlewares.push(logger)
}

export const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(...middlewares));
export const persistor = persistStore(store);

sagaMiddleware.run(fetchGalleryStart); //inside run we pass each individual saga

const exportedObject = {
    store,
    persistor,
};
export default exportedObject;
```

The app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import Header from './components/header/header.component.jsx';
import Footer from './components/footer/footer.component.jsx';
import HomePage from './pages/homepage/homepage.component.jsx';
import Contact from './pages/contact/contact.component.jsx';
import About from './pages/about/about.component.jsx';

class App extends React.Component  {
 
render () {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Header />
          <div className="wrapper">
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
            <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
            <Route path="/about" component={About} />

            <Route path="*">error</Route>
          </Switch>
          </div>
          <Footer/>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    );
  }
  
};

export default  App
```

When I open the app in the browser, the app is not rendered on the root, page stays blank.
Could you please help me where to look? I am pretty lost how to approach this since i receive no error.

Thank you for your time

Comment: Is that the complete code? `App` doesn't appear to be declared.

Comment: Hello, you are totally right, I am sorry, I have not copied the App corrently, now I copied again. The app indeed is declared, I just tried to remove the clutter and by accident removed the class App...

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your render()... method with a class component like this:

```
class App extends React.Component {
 render() {
  return ();
 }
}
export default App;
```

To declare App correct.
Or get rid of render() method and do a function:

```
funciton App() => {
 return (<div></div>);
}
export default App;
```

Hope I could help you and have fun!

Comment: Hello Markus-SO I have made a small mistake when copying the code, could you please be so kind to take a look again?

Comment: @dulinDis if you copied your store.js correct, for my first quick overview, afai remember (not 100% know), createStore is like a callBack function and it should look like this: `export const store = createStore(
  () => rootReducer,
  applyMiddleware(...middlewares)
);` Take a look to the addition parentheses and arrow callback `() =>`